# How do I remove all but the last occurrence of a string?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I am trying to remove all occurrences of `2016/01/30 14:52:51:` but the last one. I tried this:

```
awk '{gsub(//,"2016/01/30 14:52:51: ",$1);print}'
```

to replace all but the last occurrence with nothing, but that just duplicated `2016/01/30 14:52:51:` 4 times with slightly different numbers.

Comment: I'm not sed-savvy enough, but I imagine if you could anchor the last occurrence of the string, you could do a search/replace/branch loop for the initial matches. e.g. search for "(.*)text(.*)text(ending pattern)$", replace with 1 & 3, repeat

Comment: Are you trying to remove the occurrences in every line or the file. Could you give an example of your input, script and output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one problem with the script, plus the problem statement needs some clarification:

- the gsub call has the regular expression in the wrong parameter
- updating `$1` has no effect on `$0` (the value used in the `print` statement)
- OP did not clarify if the intent was to leave the last occurrence on a line untouched, or only the last line containing the date (the latter is more likely).

Here is a script which incorporates those fixes and assumptions:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
BEGIN { row=0; fixup = -1; }
{
    before[row] = $0;
    gsub("2016/01/30 14:52:51: ", "", $0);
    if ( $0 != before[row] ) {
            fixup = row;
    }
    after[row++] = $0;
}
END {
    if (fixup >= 0) {
            after[fixup] = before[fixup];
    }
    for (n = 0; n < row; ++n) {
            print after[n];
    }
}
'
```

(using two arrays is less efficient, but allows further modification with less effort than without the `before` array).

I tested this by making an input file (`foo.in`):

```
1awk '{gsub(//,"2016/01/30 14:52:51: ",$1);print}'
2awk '{gsub(//,"2016/01/30 14:52:51: ",$1);print}'
3awk '{gsub(//,"2016/01/30 14:52:51: ",$1);print}'
4awk '{gsub(//,"2016/01/30 14:52:51: ",$1);print}'
```

and running the script like this:

```
./foo <foo.in
```

and got

```
1awk '{gsub(//,"",$1);print}'
2awk '{gsub(//,"",$1);print}'
3awk '{gsub(//,"",$1);print}'
4awk '{gsub(//,"2016/01/30 14:52:51: ",$1);print}'
```

Comment: I actually didn't understand the script but it was someone who did the same as me and I simply replaced the values with my own. (Also, your answer doesn't seem to work for me, I tried this on a file with only two occurences and it's been running for 20 minutes with nothing happening. (I have restarted and ran again too, so it's not a one time problem).

Comment: You may have not redirected input to awk, e.g., the `<` character.  Also, clarifying your problem with sample input would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

My contribution is a POSIX-compliant ed alternative to Thomas Dickey's AWK; it makes the same assumptions:

```
printf '%s\n' '1;?2016/01/30 14:52:51: ?' '1,.-g//s///' w q | ed filename
```

ed's ability to traverse the file backwards makes short work of this task.